# Autoselect picker row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've been looking for quite a while after an answer for this, but can't seem to fint the solution...
Whenever I open my picker I need to pull the screen a little bit in order for the first row to get "picked" otherwise it will return a blank string.
Is there a way to by default autoselect the first row so that you wont need to do this motion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated
```

to set any default value that you want.

Comment: I'm sorry for taking your time... I couldn't get the first two answers to work after a few tries, and then I figured I could solve it with a simple if parameter. You always get smarter right after you ask...

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
[pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO]
```

In your viewDidLoad method.

Comment: I'm sorry for taking your time... I couldn't get the first two answers to work after a few tries, and then I figured I could solve it with a simple if parameter. You always get smarter right after you ask...

Answer (score 0):

You just declare NSString in your .h file

```
NSString *strVal;
```

then in your viewDidLoad method assign your default value to the string

```
strVal=your default value;
```

and your delegate method :

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:

(NSInteger)component
{
    strVal=assign element;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you but this doesn't seem to answer the question :)

Comment: @JeroenMoons: If you are not scrolling the picker then delegate methods will not called thats why it returns empty string. If i assign default value to the string in viewDidLoad itself then i will not get empty string.After scrolling the picker delegate method will called and assign selected value to the string .The answer given below is also fine but i have implemented this in above way.

Comment: Well, yes that would work for the program logic. It will not enhance the user experience though.

Comment: Yes,But I don't know how it will affect on user experience?

Comment: I'm sorry for taking your time... I couldn't get the first two answers to work after a few tries, and then I figured I could solve it with a simple if parameter. You always get smarter right after you ask...